# Save Downloading File on Phone

Tags: android, path, download

I google on online that there is a way to save on the phone, if the phone has an SD-Card.

I tested on my friend's phone, is working fine. But My Galaxy Nexus doesn't have a SD-Card. The file is usually saved in Downloads Folder.

Is this Downloads Folder a new Feature added in Android Cream Sandwich?

If or If not, is there a way to get the default saving path on the phone? No matter it is android 2.0, 4.0, Galaxy Nexus, G1. etc.

Comment: Actually what did you try to download?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`Environment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) class. `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` will show you the default save location for downloads.

This was added in API level 8.

Either way, you can use `getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the SD card and reference it via the `File` class.